# Detect and Enter Input on a prompt in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I'm working on a shell script, which has lot of network calls and installations. When it is executed I need to enter yes/no for each prompt. Which is fine.

But now i have a requirement to run it as cron. In which case i won't be able to give inputs for each of the prompt that comes up.
Is there any way I can automate this or have some mechanism of knowing in script that a prompt has come up?

Comment: How about your redesign your script to accept options so that it doesn't need user action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `yes` command to answer interactive prompts,

```
yes Y | ./script.sh
```

The above syntax constantly puts the string `Y` to all your prompts. You can pass the string as you need after `yes`.

You can also use `expect` tool meant for this, but you need to know the exact prompt message for capturing and responding to it accordingly. If your prompt is simple and just need a simple input to pass `yes` would be the right tool.

Also you can use `bash` built-in `printf`, but you need to add the responses manually depending upon the number of prompts you have to respond to, e.g.

```
printf 'Y\nY\nY\n' | ./script.sh
```

to send response as `Y` for three prompts. As again, to avoid doing this manually, prefer using the `yes` command.